# Flutter Firebase listen runs twice when data changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter application that is using Cloud Firestore. My application needs to listen for changes in a document but does not need to change any UI elements hence I am using `.listen()` (Please correct me if I should be using stream builder instead). I have noticed that per change in data, the below print statement runs twice. Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

```
static Future<void> checkForRequests() async {
    print('Request call initiated');
    try {
       _firestore
          .collection('Requests')
          .where('UsersList', arrayContains: _auth.currentUser.uid)
          .snapshots()
          .listen((event) {
        event.docs.forEach((element) {
          print('Checking for requests');
          final person = element.get('ActionRequiredBy');
          if (person == _auth.currentUser.uid) {
            final stage = element.get('Stage');
            final requestID = element.get('ConversationID');
            switch (stage) {
              case 3:
                {

                  JPAKEStages.stage3(requestID);
                }
                break;
              case 4:
                {

                  JPAKEStages.stage4(requestID);
                }
                break;
              case 5:
                {

                  JPAKEStages.stage5(requestID);
                }
                break;
              case -1:{
              }
              break;
              default:
                {
                  return;
                }
            }
          }
          return;
        });
      });
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception);
    }
  }
```

There is just a single document but the print statement 'Checking requests' gets called twice every time there is a change in that document.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you created a listener 2 times. Be sure that your code that creates a listener like

```
.listen(
```

is not called twice.